# Protractor by.repeater not finding anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

How do I select the following repeater with Protractor?

```
<a ng-repeat="item in filteredItems = (items | filter:'abc')">{{item}}</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`by.exactRepeater()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater).

Looking into the [source code](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/e7873093ada02ad6c9d6e190b7184775ab3686ce/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L168), you can see that the `exactRepeater` checks the part of the repeater coming before the "track by", "|" and "as". It means that you cannot use:

```
element.all(by.exactRepeater("item in filteredItems"));
```

but have to use the following:

```
element.all(by.exactRepeater("item in filteredItems = (items"));
```

which, I agree, does not look particularly readable. Created an issue here:

- [Should by.exactRepeater also split by "="?](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2335)

UPDATE: the issue is now fixed (that was really quick, thanks to @sjelin) in the trunk.

---

And, alternatively, you can always locate it in a usual selenium-ish way:

```
element.all(by.css('a[ng-repeat^="item in filteredItems"]'));
element.all(by.xpath('//a[starts-with(@ng-repeat, "item in filteredItems")]'));
```

Comment: Great answer. I was just about to dig in the source code as well, protractor is such a time sink... ugh.

Comment: @Unidan yeah, sorry for the edits, mixed the locators at first. Which option(s) eventually worked? Thanks.

Comment: Your second example (`by.exactRepeater("item in filteredItems = (items"))`). I edited by your suggestions and re-ran every time you edited until it worked haha :). Accepting as answer as soon as SO allows me.

Comment: @Unidan FYI, updated with an linked protractor issue, follow it if interested. Thanks!

Comment: @alexce Saw it, nice!